# protocol buffers with c & c++

Tags: c++, c, protocol-buffers

Now i have a c/s program with protocol buffers(using c++). I want to rewrite the server with c. But in the .proto file there are many services. The program implements the rpc itself, while protocol buffers-c provides another. I want someone to show me how to implement this examples.

```
service {
    rpc foo (what) returns(what);
}
```

How can write this service, while the client is in c++ and server in c.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt anyone will go through the trouble and give you an example beyond what is already [documented](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/wiki/Generated_Code) (see Services subsection).

> want to know how to implement the client part with c++.

Just keep the client you already have (i.e. don't rewrite it).

The protocol buffers themselves are language-independent; properly written client does not care what language the server is implemented in, and vice versa.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i still want to know how to implement the client part with c++.